# how curl in php use update?

Tags: php, curl

send data for update by put method

```
{{ Form::model($books, array('route' => array('package.update', $books->id), 'method' => 'put', 'files'=>'true')) }}
```

and my controller

```
enter code here
```

**strong text**

```
$ch = curl_init();
$file = $data['file'];  
$data['title'] = $data['course_name'];
if (isset($data['file']))
    $data['file'] = new CURLFile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'application/pdf',$_FILES['file']['name']);
$data['resource_id'] = $book->urnid;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
print_r(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

it gives

```
{"detail":"Method 'PUT' not allowed."}
```

but try also through post and patch method still same error give.